# How do I handle cancelling of publishers in Combine's Future functions?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine, anycancellable

In `RxSwift` you can create a reactive function something like this:

```
func aFunc() -> Observable<Void> {
    return Observable.create({ emitter in
        let disposable = Observable
            .combineLatest(someObservable,
                           someOtherObservable)
                .subscribe(onNext: { responseA, responseB in
                    // do stuff
                })

                return Disposables.create {
                    disposable.dispose()
                }
            })
        }
```

In `Combine` you can achieve similar results using `Future`:

```
func aFunc() -> Future<Void, Error> {
    return Future { promise in
        somePublisher
            .combineLatest(someObservable,
                           someOtherObservable)
                .sink{ responseA, responseB in
                    // do stuff
                }
            })
        }
```

The thing I don't quite get is that the `Future` doesn't seem to return its equivalent of `RxSwift's`

```
return Disposables.create {
    disposable.dispose()
}
```

How is standard practice to handle disposing/cancelling of publishers in a `Future`?

I tried simply adding:

```
_ = somePublisher...
```

But then the publisher isn't kept alive and will simply not activate at all.
Should I just hook on `.store(in: &cancellables)` to the end of the `publisher`. But them, when do I cancel those `cancellables`? Or is there some way of returning cancellables, like in `RxSwift`? What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of `Publisher` you are trying to create. Does it only publish *once*? If not, then a `Future` is not appropriate. And even if it does, why do you need a `Future` when you can manipulate the `combineLatest` publisher instead?

Comment: The only thing that's relevant in this question is how combine should handle publishers inside of the Future. RxSwift does it using 

return Disposables.create {
    disposable.dispose()
}

How does it work with combine?

Comment: I don't think Combine is designed to "handle publishers inside of the `Future`". Why would you ever want to "nest" publishers like that, when you can just operate on the "inner" publisher directly? This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). `Future` is not the same as `Observable.create`.

Comment: "Future is not the same as Observable.create" 
Really? Aren't they sort of the same?

Comment: No. `Future` is a very specific publisher that either publishes one single element and then completes, or throws an error. `Observable.create` is a *lot* more general than that.

Comment: Perhaps putting it this way makes it clearer why they are not the same - the closure that `Observable.create` takes is used to implement the `Observable.subscribe(_:)` method, but the closure that `Future` takes is used to implement the `Publisher.receive(subscriber:)` method, which I don't think is a thing in RxSwift. The implementation of the `Publisher.subscribe(_:)` on the other hand, is an extension method and so cannot be changed.

Comment: More importantly, a Future is eager and *can't* be disposed/cancelled once it starts. That's why it’s creator doesn’t have a way to cancel it. I agree that the RxSwift code is nonsensical. Just use the Observables you have.

Comment: Thanks for clearing all of that up, I guess I have to find another way to restructure my streams to combine publishers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, you don't. A Combine Future is like an RxSwift Single that can't be canceled once it starts.